is loopsound in notifee supposed to work on ios?
I set up a trigger with loopSound property set to true for both android and ios. It works on android, but, on ios the audio plays only once. Doing some research i found that ios was not allowing alarm audio to play for longer that 30 secs. I wander if that changed and if loopSound is supposed to work on ios. Thank you for any insights.
"@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
"react-native": "0.74.3",
